# Visualisation Tool: Coordinate Systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, math-software, visualization

I'm looking for a tool/program for the visualisation of different coordinate systems for three-dimensional space.

I would like to create simple illustrations and I would like to save the result as a .pdf (or .png etc.)

Examples of coordinate systems are:

- Spherical coordinates
- Cartesian coordinates
- Local tangent plane coordinates
- ...

I am not familiar with math tools. Is there any software that can be used to construct coordinate systems?

**EDIT:**

I would work with Python, but I'm looking for simpler solutions first.
Wikipedia has nice illustrations. Do you eventually know how they are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe geogebra is what you're looking for or TikZ with LaTeX, on wikipedia all sorts of tools can be used, there are no specific tools for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give TikZ a try

Comment: @Sylvia See also [Wikipedia List of Graphical Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_information_graphics_software).  Further, within the realm of Latex, the *big 3* are PSTricks, PGF-Tikz, and Asymptote.  All three are extremely powerful, and all three have challenging learning curves.  Typically, a Latex user might spend a week or two briefly looking at all three, choose one of the three, and stick with it.  I went with Asymptote, despite its *hard to read, not up to date* documentation, because I am a retired programmer.  So, Asymptote is compatible with my skills.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks a lot! Why did you chose Asymptote?

Comment: @Sylvia Originally, I went with PSTricks about 23 years ago.  About 20 years ago, Asymptote was born.  I found that the PSTricks documentation was disjointed, and I disliked having to purchase PSTricks consolidated documentation.  Further, I found that truly unlocking Asymptote's power required at least some programming skills, which I already have.  Ironically, in the last 10 years, while Asymptote has continued to grow, becoming more powerful, its documentation has become poor.  ...see next comment

Comment: @Sylvia To resolve questions because the Asymptote documentation is confusing or incomplete, you sometimes have to post a question either [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).